# A sample of finding the Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me with this problem:
Find the JCF of A given $A^2-I=0$.

Here's what I tried:

This implies that $m_A|(x^2-1)$. And so $m_A\in\{x-1,x+1,x^2-1\}.$ $m_A=x-\lambda$ if and only if $A=\lambda I$. Thus $m_A=x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1).$ Then the JCF of $A$ is of the form $-I_k\oplus I_{n-k}.$

Did I arrive at the right answer? I think I still have something to do with the sizes of $Is$.

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: The cases $A=\pm I$ don't get excluded. So, one doesn't really get to say "Thus $m_A=x^2-1$". In the final expression the dimension of $A$ is $2n$. Is it given that the dimension of $A$ is even?

Comment: Umm. But in my answer I indeed included $\pm I$. Can you please expound? Oh yeah right I'm sorry. It should be $n-k$.

Comment: I only mean the moment when you say "Thus $m_A=x^2-1$".

Comment: Oh I get it. Do you mean I should omit the equality and instead only have $m_A=(x-1)(x+1)?$

Comment: No, I only mean that one doesn't deduce that the minimal polynomial is $x^2-1$. All three cases $\{x-1,x+2,x^2-1\}$ that you wrote are possible.